# IIS Admin Service stuck at "Starting" status

Tags: service, iis

I'm having some trouble restarting IIS, and I took a look and see that the IIS Admin Service is in the "Starting" status. I'm not able to Start/Stop it manually. All of the context menu options for this are disabled. Any ideas?

My system settings are:

IIS7 on Windows 7
I have the following ISAPI/CGI Restrictions:
ASP.NET v2.0.50727 x32/x64
ASP.NET v4.0.30319 x32/x64

Comment: Do you have any relevant events in the System log? What IIS? What OS?

Comment: Right, should have specified all of that info.

Running IIS7 on Windows 7.

I can see this error from Event Viewer concerning that service: 

The IIS Admin Service service terminated with the following error: 
The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Are you running an ASP.NET application? IIS7 is very stripped down by default. This sounds like a missing dependency, e.g. ASP.NET is not installed by default.

Comment: @Somantra, I edited my original post to reflect more info.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the issue: [http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7023&eventno=345&source=Service Control Manager&phase=1](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7023&eventno=345&source=Service%20Control%20Manager&phase=1)

http://kbalertz.com/903072/receive-error-message-installation-responding-start-Admin-service.aspx

In my experience with IIS7, certain issues are most easily resolved by reinstalling IIS. This may be one of those instances. In the links provided, one of the prescribed resolutions is to reinstall IIS.

Take a look and see if that helps.